# ModRewrite - rewrite rule help needed

Tags: apache, web

I have little question about modrewrite - rewriterule.

Is it possilbe to make a redirect from link with # to another file or link?
For example, if my current link is http://example.com/data/#11 can i make all that links act as a http://example.com/path/file.pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

RedirectMatch 301 data/#11(.*) /path/file.pdf/$1